# XWPFTable generation

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want to create an XWPFTable with multiple columns. And I am inserting the values to the row numbers starting from 0. But the thing is, 1st row's content is getting appended to the 0th row's. Another thing is, when i just write to 1st row, its on top row.
So is it that I need to assume both getRow(0) and getRow(1) points to the topmost row?? Thanks in advance.

```
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFTable table=doc.createTable(3,3);
    table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("A");
    table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("B");
    table.getRow(0).getCell(2).setText("C");

    table.getRow(1).getCell(0).setText("one");
    table.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("two");
    table.getRow(1).getCell(2).setText("three");

    table.getRow(2).getCell(0).setText("XXX");
    table.getRow(2).getCell(1).setText("YYYYY");
    table.getRow(2).getCell(2).setText("ZZZZZZ");
```

The table generated is:

Aone    Btwo    Cthree
XXX     YYYYY   ZZZZZZ

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I see the table as it should be in MS Office (2010). There are some layout differences in OpenOffice rendering but it is still correct. Is that the code you tried? What version of POI are you using? What kind of Office suite are you using?

This is what I tested.

```
package com.ecinev.poitest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;

public class TestPoi2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(3, 3);
        table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("A");
        table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("B");
        table.getRow(0).getCell(2).setText("C");

        table.getRow(1).getCell(0).setText("one");
        table.getRow(1).getCell(1).setText("two");
        table.getRow(1).getCell(2).setText("three");

        table.getRow(2).getCell(0).setText("XXX");
        table.getRow(2).getCell(1).setText("YYYYY");
        table.getRow(2).getCell(2).setText("ZZZZZZ");

        doc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "/Users/myfolder/Documents/empty.docx")));
    }
}
```

Comment: the document generated if opened in wordpad, it looks fine(faced same problem in open office.). Jars i have used are dom4j-1.6 , poi-3.10-beta1 , poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029 , poi-ooxml-schemas and xmlbeans-2.3.0.          So it is poi 3.10

Comment: Docx files are xml based, zipped archives. I would suggest you to create a file containing the requested table with your office suite. Then you can unzip the docx and look for a document.xml file. Compare it with the same file produced by poi library and maybe you will find the problem.